# Angular 7 build: How to remove output hash and default~<view1>~<module1> file?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

I've build angular app using:

`ng build --prod --named-chunks --output-hashing=none`

It output `module-A.js`, `module-B.js` as expected but there are some files like `default~<view1>~<module-1>~123xzy.js`. (In runtime.js these default files are required)

I want to separate `module-A.js` to another domain but I must move also `default~<view1>~<module-1>~123xzy.js`, so it also affect `view1`.

How can I remove such `default~<view1>~<module-1>~123xzy.js`? I.e. Config to combine `default~<view1>~<module-1>~123xzy.js` into `module-A.js`? (And I don't want refactor all structure code to eliminate such files, is there any other lighter way?)

Answer (score 19):

You can use

```
ng build --prod --output-hashing none
```

or only

```
ng build --prod
```

Ref link

1. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8344
2. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1833

Comment: Thank, but it doesn't work. It's not bug of Angular; I need a way to split app code to one JS file not distribute it to several file .i.e code of module-1 in both module-1.js and default~<module-1>.js

Answer (score 0):

try adding common-chunks abd move with your separated modules