# angular component not rendered inside razor view

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, razor

I have an existing MVC Core Web Application. Wanna add an angular component which calls a WebAPI(.Net Core) inside an existing razor view.

created an angular project(ClientApp) inside my existing MVC Core Web App. Changed the output path in angular.json to '`../wwwroot/dist`' and root to '`ClientApp`'.

for now just added a heading element inside app component .

and build the angular project(ng build)...which created the angular js files inside wwwroot/dist folder...(ps ref the image added)

Added `<app-root></app-root>` inside my razor view.

Added script reference in _layout.cshtml

```
<script src=”~/dist/inline.bundle.js” asp-append-version=”true”></script>
<script src=”~/dist/polyfills.bundle.js” asp-append-version=”true”></script>
<script src=”~/dist/styles.bundle.js” asp-append-version=”true”></script>
<script src=”~/dist/vendor.bundle.js” asp-append-version=”true”></script>
<script src=”~/dist/main.bundle.js” asp-append-version=”true”></script>
```

[image]

The app component is not rendering inside the razor view.

If the script tags are replaced by below

```
<script src="~/dist/runtime.e57db3062a73ecc3.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="~/dist/polyfills.665d8e80eb7ecf9e.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="~/dist/main.c013bbaba2785fad.js" type="module"></script>
```

then the component rendered inside the razor view....How to reference this dynamic angular scripts in _layouts file.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to fix this

1. Make a bundle of angular generated js files then add ref of that file in your view. Here is link you can check how to bundle files
   [How to bundle JavaScript and CSS in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61511668/how-to-bundle-javascript-and-css-in-visual-studio)
2. You can force angular cli to create un-hashed file name here is link that might help you.
   [Angular 7 build: How to remove output hash and default~<view1>~<module1> file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59367080/angular-7-build-how-to-remove-output-hash-and-defaultview1module1-file)